# xp_cmdshell copy command seldom fails

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, windows-server-2003, xp-cmdshell

I am running SQL Server 2005 on Windows Server 2003 machine.

I have a requirement to accumulate small text files into a bigger one.

So I use

```
exec xp_cmdshell @sql
```

where @sql=

```
'copy /b'+@sourcePath+@sourceFile+' '+@destinationPath+@NewFileName
```

Both the source and destination paths are on a separate server.

Seldom this process fails and I don't find anything else in the event or SQL Server logs.

The Surface Area Config for xp_cmdshell is also enabled.

Please help.....

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this on my sql server 2005 and `EXEC dbo.xp_cmdshell` always returns output (even in the case of a bogus command) in the form of a table. For C#, if you call this code with [ExecuteNonQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx), then call it with [ExecuteReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executereader%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) and read the output. Alternatively, you could dump the output in a table so that you can look at it later at your leisure. Create a table like this :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[xp_cmdShellOutput](
    [errorMsg] [nvarchar](max) NULL
)
```

and then use this code :

```
DECLARE @sql AS VARCHAR(600)

SELECT  @sql = '<your command>'

INSERT  dbo.xp_cmdShellOutput(errorMsg)
EXEC dbo.xp_cmdshell @sql
```

Comment: Hi Sem, Thanks! I too thought this but its a legacy code in SQL that I m debugging and need help on it. Also, its copying in binary i.e. copy /b

Comment: @Daniel I'm not really following what you want to say. You say it's legacy code. Do you mean you don't get any output from the `EXEC dbo.xp_cmdshell` at all ?

Comment: @Sem, the code is working fine but once a week it fails and so to debug it i added catches and found the error at this xp_cmdshell copy command. Also, I didn't get any system or application logs at the time of failure to correlate the issue.

Comment: @Daniel. So, your problem is solved then (as you can get debugging info)? (That you didn't get any logs is not that weird. From the point of view of the OS `dbo.xp_cmdshell` is just a command executed in the shell by a user. Why should it log ? If it fails, the user is supposed to read the error info provided by the command).

Comment: @Sem, All I get is SQLSTATE 42000 and ERROR 50000 (signifies my custom error log). I am not able to find the root cause of the error. On books online & @net I learnt that SQLSTATE 42000 is quite generic.

Comment: @Daniel If you use the piece of code in my answer and dump the info of the `copy` command into a table, you should be able to figure out what's the problem.